# Flickering using WM_DRAWITEM

Tags: c++, winapi

It seems like I can't get pass this issue with owner-draw controls. I've super-classed a status control. I am trying to customize but still retain the same functionality. Basically, I want to change the background and text. I'm using Direct2d (or ID2D1DCRenderTarget interface) for the drawing. I have successful changed the background by using WM_NCPAINT; although, you can use WM_ERASEBKGRND if you want. However, both methods acted as a control in my experiment and flickering still occurred. Moreover, flickering doesn't occur when the WPARAM of SB_SETTEXT is **NOT SET** to SBT_OWNERDRAW. Therefore, I came to a conclusion that WM_DRAWITEM is the culprit. Is there anyway I can fix this flickering issue with owner-draw statusbar?

Comment: I assume this control is has a custom window class, correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid flickering if you turn on double buffering for you control.

Set the WS_EX_COMPOSITED extended style:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx

e.g. when handling WM_CREATE, call (WTL or MFC):

```
ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_COMPOSITED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like I figured it out. When super-classing a status-bar follow these sets to avoid flickering.

**Note: This has only been tested with visual styles turned off. SetWindowTheme(hWndStatus, L"", L"");
Also, the parent window must have WS_CLIPCHILDREN set in the style parameter during window creation.

1: Override WM_SIZE. Make a call to InvalidateRect(m_hWnd, NULL, TRUE) and return 0 unless you want the default sizing; in this case, call CallWindowProc.

2: Override WM_ERASEBKGND and return -1.

3: Override WM_NCPAINT and place your drawing code here.

Handling WM_NCPAINT. People seem to have trouble understanding how to handle WM_NCPAINT. Here is how I do it.

```
if (wParam == 1) {
    hdc = GetWindowDC(m_hWnd);
} else {
    hdc = GetDCEx(m_hWnd, (HRGN) wParam, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_INTERSECTRGN | DCX_CACHE);
}
```

Then do drawing with the DC.

4: In the parent procedure (WndProc or whatever) call SetWindowPos(..., SWP_DRAWFRAME) with the handle to the statusbar. This will resize your statusbar.

5: Send a message via SendMessage(hWndStatusbar, SB_SETPARTS, 1, (LPARAM) &parts);

6: Send a message via SendMessage(hWndStatusbar, SB_SETTEXT, LOBYTE(0) | SBT_OWNERDRAW, L"Ready"). Sample code for WM_DRAWITEM:

```
...
WM_DRAWITEM:
LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT) lParam;

m_pFramework->m_pD2D1RenderTarget->BindDC(lpDIS->hDC, &lpDIS->rcItem);

m_pFramework->m_pD2D1RenderTarget->BeginDraw();

m_pFramework->m_pD2D1RenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::CadetBlue));

D2D1_RECT_F rf = D2D1::RectF(
    PixeltoDipX(lpDIS->rcItem.left),
    PixeltoDipY(lpDIS->rcItem.top),
    PixeltoDipX(lpDIS->rcItem.right),
    PixeltoDipY(lpDIS->rcItem.bottom)
    );

m_pFramework->m_pD2D1RenderTarget->DrawText(
    (LPCWSTR) lpDIS->itemData,
    wcslen((WCHAR*) lpDIS->itemData) + 1,
    m_pFramework->m_pTextFormat,
    rf,
    m_d2dCaptionTextColor
    );

m_pFramework->m_pD2D1RenderTarget->EndDraw();
break;
....
```

This should stop flickering. Also, do not call InvalidateRect(hWndStatus, NULL, TRUE) in the parent's WM_SIZE. This was the main reason it flickered.